# How to get a bird eye view of distorted football pitch panorama obtained by stitching of 2 images?

Tags: opencv, distortion, image-stitching, panoramas

I want to get a bird's eye view of a panorama like the one below. As I mentioned in the title, it was obtained by stitching images from 2 cameras. Unfortunately, I don't know the intrinsic and extrinsic parameters for both of them. Could you suggest an approach to tackle this problem?

[image: panorama]

Comment: Without undistortion before stitching you likely wont get any useful birds eye view.

Comment: @Micka, I understand that. However, I can not access original images. So. maybe, I should undistort the panorama. Can you recommend to me where to start? To get a bird's eye view, I tried to manually make a correspondence of image points to top-view grid ones and apply interpolation. That gave me bad results(

Comment: guess the projection type. is it equirectangular? cylindrical? it's certainly not planar ("normal") because I see more than 180 degrees. -- distortion near the bottom looks to me like equirectangular. if it's that, the sphere is not level.